# C# C++ Interop Delegate

Tags: c#, c++, delegates, interop, structure

I would like to preface this with the fact I have no formal C++ training, so if you have suggestions, please provide in a way that a super noob can implement.
Thank you in advance.
What I am trying to do is call a C++ function from C# pass in a structure and a delegate.
My code works, but if I access a value in the delegate, I receive this error:
[image: Delegate error image]

Here is my c# code:

```
public delegate void CallBackMethodDelegate(MP4CreateClipProcessingData data);

[DllImport("libmp4v2.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
public extern static string MP4CreateClip(ref MP4CreateClipProcessingData data, CallBackMethodDelegate del);
```

And here is my C++ Code:

```
struct MP4CreateClipProcessingData
{
    bool err;
    char* sourcePath;
    char* targetPath;
    char* error;
    uint32_t startTime;
    uint32_t duration;
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void MP4CreateClip(MP4CreateClipProcessingData data, void (_stdcall *func)(MP4CreateClipProcessingData))
{
    func(data);
}
```

This is where, in my C# code I call the function:

```
var data = new NativeMethods.MP4CreateClipProcessingData(file, Path.Combine(targetPath, Path.GetFileName(file).ToString()));
NativeMethods.CallBackMethodDelegate retDel = new NativeMethods.CallBackMethodDelegate(NativeMethods.returnCall);
NativeMethods.MP4CreateClip(ref data, retDel);
```

Comment: show the code you use to pass the delegate. Please ensure the delegate is referred somewher in your code other than the unmanaged call in order to avoid them colelcted by the GC

Comment: Sorry, I was having issues with the markup, its all there now. Also, I have tried: GC.KeepAlive(NativeMethods.MP4CreateClip(ref data, retDel)); to no avail....

Comment: You need to keep a reference to the delegate so that it does not get garbage collected.  `GC.KeepAlive` only keeps the delegate alive for execution *prior* to the `KeepAlive` function call. (`KeepAlive` itself does not do anything except reference the variable.)

Comment: show c# code you use to declare MP4CreateClipProcessingData.

Comment: So I found that the problem is that if in the Delegate function I call Console.WriteLine, it throws that error.

Comment: The CallingConvention is wrong, it is Cdecl.  It also isn't ref data, just data.

Comment: @hans-passant Hi, can you please elaborate the 'CallingConvention is wrong statement'? I have tried ref data and data, both result in an error when I try to access any data from the struct in the delegate.

Comment: Well, MP4CreateClip is not declared __stdcall.  And it doesn't take a MP4CreateClipProcessingData*, the struct is passed by value.  There may well be other mistakes, you didn't post a complete snippet.

Comment: You might find the page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367eeye0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx useful (take a look to call GCHandle::Alloc) and a lot of info about interop at http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries